# Return Successful Observable On Route Resolve Call Failure?

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-router, resolve

If an observable inside a route resolver fails, the Angular router does not navigate to the route. I want to get around this by wrapping my call in another observable, which always successfully returns, like so:

```
private fetchUserDataOrReturnNullIfError(url: string, httpOptions: any): Observable<any> {

  const getLoggedInUserDataOrNullIfCallFails: Observable<any> = new Observable(observer =>  {
  this.httpClient.get(url, httpOptions).subscribe(userData => {
    console.log('Got user data: ', userData);
    observer.next(userData);
  }, err => {
    console.log('Call failed');
    observer.next('lol');
  });
});

return getLoggedInUserDataOrNullIfCallFails;
  }
```

My resolve looks like this:

```
  resolve(): Observable<any> {  
    //stuff and things
    return this.fetchUserDataOrReturnNullIfError(url, httpOptions);
  }
```

My understanding was that the inner observable would error, and the outer observable would successfully call `next`, thereby the route would successfully resolve. This isn't happening.

What am I doing wrong / how do I solve this?

My goal is for the resolve to return the result of the call, if successful, and to return `lol` if failing, but to always go to the next route.

Answer (score 2):

I overcomplicate the **** out of that. The answer is:

```
return this.httpClient.get(url, httpOptions).pipe(
  catchError(err => of(null))
);
```

`catchError` must return a new Observable, and that gets passed on to the resolver. I am actually still not sure why my original method didn't work, but it could have something to do with the fact that I am using old syntax and RxJS compat.

Source: https://blog.angular-university.io/rxjs-error-handling/